# Fractal ellipse recursion within constructor

Tags: java, recursion

I am starting my journey into recursion and am trying to create a fractal class that recurses within its constructor. This class is supposed to take a parent ellipse, place 4 smaller, child ellipses on its circumference and then keeps recursing to a maxdepth while placing 4 child ellipses on each of the previous children.

My current progress produces 1 parent ellipse, and 4 children ( after calling a draw method on the "children" array). My question is: how do I recurse on the children? I am really quite unsure where to start.

```
 public FractalEllipse( int depth, Point p, int w, int h )
 {
    setFrame( p.x, p.y, w, h );

    if ( depth < numDepth )
    {
        children = new FractalEllipse[numChildren];
        for ( int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++ )
        { 
            int height = ( int )( h * sizeRatio );
            int width = ( int ) ( w * sizeRatio );
            int centerX = ( int ) ( this.getCenterX( ) - ( width / 2 ) );
            int centerY = ( int ) ( this.getCenterY( ) - ( height / 2 ) );
            double radX = Math.toRadians( ( 360 / numChildren ) * i );
            double radY = Math.toRadians( ( 360 / numChildren ) * i );


            int x = ( int ) ( centerX + ( ( w / 2 ) ) *  Math.cos( radX ) );
            int y = ( int ) ( centerY + ( ( h / 2 ) ) *  Math.sin( radY ) );

            FractalEllipse child = new FractalEllipse( depth + 1,
                              new Point( x, y ), width, height ); 

            children[i] = child;

        } 
    } else
    {

    }
}
```

Sorry here is the full draw method:

```
public void draw( Graphics2D context ) 
{
    Color saveColor = context.getColor();

    Color myColor = Color.MAGENTA;
    context.setColor( myColor );

    // draw myself
    if ( fill )        
        context.fill( this );
    else
        context.draw( this );

    context.setColor( Color.CYAN );

    for ( int i = 0; i < children.length; i++ )
    {
            context.fill( children[i] ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Who calls `context.fill` on the root ellipse (the one that isn't a child of anything else)?  Or do you not want to fill that one?

Comment: Sorry! Edited to add full draw method

Answer (score 0):

Since the `draw` method causes a fractal ellipse to either draw or fill itself, the parent doesn't need to call `context.draw` or `context.fill` on the children.  Instead, if you call the children's `draw` method recursively, they will call `context.draw` or `context.fill` on themselves.  Then they will do the same for their children.

Therefore, the loop in the `draw` method should look something like:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < children.length; i++ )
{
        children[i].draw(); 
}
```

or, using Java's enhanced `for` loop:

```
for (FractalEllipse child : children) {
    child.draw();
}
```

The one thing that isn't clear is the `fill` variable.  You used this in the `draw` method but haven't shown how it's defined or how it's set.  Assuming that you want the parent and all the descendants to have either their outlines drawn or to be filled in the same way: if `fill` is a field in the `FractalEllipse`, you'll need to make sure the `fill` field is set in the children the same way as in the parent.  If the field comes from somewhere else, you may need to add it as a parameter to the `draw` method, and make sure that `draw` includes the parameter when it calls itself recursively on its children.  I don't know what the right answer is because of missing information, but one of these two idioms is most likely what you need.

Answer (score -1):

If there are any children, You need to call the `draw` loop of the children specifically, either before or after the `context.fill(..)`.

After you included branching through children, back to the main `draw`, You must check if the children array exists. In case you are not initializing it once you reach a certain depth.